# prevent intellij from showing dialog with information about reformatted lines

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Whenever I reformat code with `Ctrl+Alt+L` IntelliJ IDEA (Android Studio) shows me this dialog:

[image]
How can I tell the studio to now show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it, the `"Show notification after reformat code action"` in `Preferences - Editor - General` should not be checked:

[image]

Comment: And now in 2020, in the new version?